# ninja gave erorr in glib gtype.h file when I try to build gnome builder

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, ninja, meson-build

I am having strange error first I am trying to build gnome builder from source from https://github.com/Alusus/gnome-builder first I try to make meson using the command meson --prefix=/usr build
then it gave me some errors in the Dependency then I solve them and when I run the command ninja -C build it gave me errors this is the first error it gave me

> rc/gstyle/gstyle-slidein.c:68:76: error: ‘G_TYPE_FLAG_FINAL’
> undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean
> ‘G_TYPE_FLAG_DERIVABLE’?    68 | G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED
> (GstyleSlidein, gstyle_slidein, GTK_TYPE_EVENT_BOX, G_TYPE_FLAG_FINAL,
> |                                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> the strangest error is that :
> usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:221:41: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
> 221 | #define G_TYPE_MAKE_FUNDAMENTAL(x)      ((GType) ((x) << G_TYPE_FUNDAMENTAL_SHIFT))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it. Even if it turns out to be a problem in glib, you still need an [mre] when you report it to them.

Comment: `I try to use ninja` how exactly do you try to use it? `when I try to build gnome builder` How exactly are you building it? What, in steps, are you doing to build it? From where did you download sources? What commands did you executed? What was the output of those commands? Please post the compiler execution line, and all the `note:` and all the other messages verbatim from the build process. `what is the error` The error is right there: `error: expected declaration specifiers ...`

Comment: thank you very much I download the source code from GitHub https://github.com/Alusus/gnome-builder when I write the command meson --prefix=/usr build  there was some Dependency missing I download them and then when I use the command ninja -C build I get this errors

Comment: there is too errors but that is the first one so I thought there is a problem in me library or in my ninja or system my system is Ubuntu 20.4

Answer (score 0):

`G_TYPE_FLAG_FINAL` was added only in GLib 2.70, so probably your installed GLib version is not high enough. The meson.build checks for this though, so I'm wondering if

> then it gave me some errors in the Dependency then I solve them

just meant that you changed the version check, which doesn't *actually* solve your problem. Either use a distro which provides a new enough version; build with flatpak-builder, or use build systems like buildstream or jhbuild.

As a side note: you're building gnome-builder from a seemingly random fork. The actual source code is at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-builder/